# Build hash index from collection in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

here is what I"m trying to get from collection of records:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "amount":"45.55",
    "currency":"CAD",
  },
  "detail": {
    "0": {
      "sku":"Product_id",
    },
    "1": {
      "sku":"Product_id",
    },
    "2": {
      "sku":"Product_id",
    }
  }
}
```

I need to loop through order items and build hash with index.

```
# Order model
order has_many :items, class_name: "LineItem"
Order.column_names
=> ["id", "amount", "currency"]

# LineItem model
LineItem.column_names
=> ["id", "sku", "order_id"]
```

Here is what I have so far but looks like I can't do this:

```
{
  transaction: {
    amount: order.subtotal,
    currency: order.currency,
  },
  detail: {
    order.items.each_with_index do |item, index|
      index: {
        sku: item.sku
      }
    end
  }
}.to_json
```

So, let's try to build nested hash separately but no luck either.

```
ha = items.each_with_index do |item, index|
       index => Hash.new(sku: item.sku)
     end
```

Comment: Please add your actual corpus of data, not just your failing code. As one example, what does `order.items` actually give you?

Comment: `order.items` returns `LineItem::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` that I can massage, transform to array for example. My problem is how to build nested hash with index from that collection of records. I need to manually set keys though, not just use model attributes

Comment: You need to provide real sample data. Nobody wants to spend time guessing what your collection looks like by working backwards from how you want it to end up.

Comment: and I'm not asking anyone to guess what my collection is. The problem is to turn any nested collection in hash with index. Could be anything product and nested images, car and nested parts, whatever stored in Db, accessible through any model. I can add anything to that collection. I have edited question with real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
body = { 
  transaction: {
    amount:"45.55",
    currency:"CAD",
  }
}

items_hash = {}
items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  h = { "#{index}" => { sku: item.sku } }
  items_hash.merge!(h)
end

details = { "transaction_detail" => items_hash }

hash = hash.merge!(details)
hash.to_json
```